# How to plot the FP-Tree using data.tree package in R

Tags: r, tree

If `data <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,2),b=c(2,4,1))` .If data frame with each row represent one branch of the fp-tree. How to represent it in below diagrammatic way [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDLKa.png) .

Answer (score 0):

Found solution using data.tree library. Took time to find solution. When parse first row 1,2 a branch is created.  When second row is parsed and while creating branch it used to override the previous branch and retain only branch 1,4. Overcame this problem by checking if node already have child with given name if  not create new else refer  to existing node.  Below is the code.                `

```
rootNode <- Node$new("Root")

for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  tmp<-rootNode
  for(j in 1:ncol(data)){

    if(is.null(Navigate(tmp, c(as.character(data[i,j]))))){
      node <- tmp$AddChild(data[i,j])
      tmp <- node
    }
    else{
      tmp <- Navigate(tmp, c(as.character(data[i,j])))
    }
  }

}

plot(rootNode)
```

`

Tested for other test cases to and it's working fine.

`data <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,2,2),b=c(1,2,4,3),c=c(2,2,2,2),d=c(2,3,3,4))`

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is:

```
data <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,2,2),b=c(1,2,4,3),c=c(2,2,2,2),d=c(2,3,3,4))
data$pathString <- paste("0", data$a, data$b, data$c, data$d, sep = "/")
tree <- as.Node(data)
```

Make sure you read the documentation, e.g. https://cran.r-project.org/package=data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html#create-a-tree-from-a-data.frame